# MOSFET with low turn on voltages

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am working on a buck boost converter to buck from 24 V to 5 V and boost from 5 V to 24 V. When I have to boost the voltage, I am unable to boost it even pass the input voltage. I think it is due to the insufficient gate voltage as I only have 5V input and I am not allowed to have any other external power. I am using IRF540 for switching. This is my simulation diagram[image]. As soon as I change the 'Pulse High Voltage' to 14V, the simulation works fine. What can I do now to get my circuit in a working state?

Comment: do not use an N-Channel to pass voltage. only to sink to ground

Answer (score 2):

The classic half-bridge buck-boost design uses a P channel MOSFET as shown: -

[image]

This means that the control of the P channel device is between 0 volts and the incoming rail (with care to ensure the gate is not overdriven beyond its maximum rating).

You are expecting an N channel device as a source follower to behave the same and, of course, this means it needs a gate drive voltage higher than the incoming power supply in order to adequately turn it on.

Many implementattions do use an N channel device as the top MOSFET but manufacture a positive rail using a bootstrapping technique.